# Disable cargo-related functionality in rust-analyzer

Tags: rust, rust-analyzer

If I don't want to use cargo for some reasons, I have the error: `could not find 'Cargo.toml'`. Is there any way to disable all `Cargo.toml`-related functionality?

I tried this:

```json
{
    "cargo": {
        "noSysroot": true,
        "sysroot": "",
        "autoreload": false,
        "buildScripts": { "enable": false }
    }
}
```

But this didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

To use rust-analyzer with single files, please check out https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/pull/8955. For larger projects that don't use Cargo, you won't be able to use rust-analyzer at the moment as per [this comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/4477#issuecomment-1335542515J).